# SSRS - date-time parameter transposition

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

This is a problem in DEV with the following configuration:

1. SSRS 2012
2. Reports configured to the language en-gb

I have recently noticed that all of my date time parameters are getting transposed when i click "View Report". So for example a GB date 08/01/2015 gets transposed to 01/08/2015 on clicking "View Report". This results in having to click the button twice for the report to show me the correct data. I have used SSRS on and off for many years and I have never noticed this before. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Obviously the parameter is switching between en-gb and en-us but why and how do i stop it?

I found a post where some one is suffering from the same problem as me but their solution seems a little overkill [issue with DateTime datatype in SQL Server Reporting Services](http://www.hilltopsit.co.uk/blog/index.php/2008/11/02/development-issue-with-datetime-datatype-in-sql-server-reporting-services/). They recomend changing your regional settings and IIS settings which may fix and or break all sorts.

Comment: I've tried to replicate your issue; however, the date is displayed as expected depending on  en-gb or  en-us

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the problem can be how do you set up the default value in the parameter definition. If instead of a fixed date, you use a dataset with a date time funtcion (something like " Select dateadd(month,-1,current_timestamp) as [Default Date]") and a default value based on that dataset, your problem could be solved, because you're not specifying any date format in the dataset's field and it should contain the right value.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I currently use an expression to set the default value for the parameter. I tried your solution of a data set containing the default value, but the problem persists. I don't know if i made it clear, but the problem exists with the default value and any selected value from the date picker.